# WPF: set trigger binding in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, triggers

I use an rectangle with an icon, to display the status of a computation. I defined a style with a datatrigger and the binding "IsCompleted" to handle the status of the computation (completed / failed = not completed). I now have more than one computation and would like to use the same type of rectancle (all with the same style and behaviour) for more than one computation. 
I know how to set the binding for IsCompleted in general for one rectangle.
How can I set the binding of the trigger in the code behind for a specific rectangle (sth. like computation1.iconStyle.IsCompleted=true)? Is this possible or do I have to define one style for each computation (which would be a lot of extra code)?

xaml:

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="NotCompleted" Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_error}" />
<VisualBrush x:Key="Completed" Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_check}" />

<Style x:Key="iconStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Rectangle}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,5,0"/>
        <Setter Property="OpacityMask" Value="{StaticResource NotCompleted}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsCompleted}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Green"/>
                <Setter Property="OpacityMask" Value ="{StaticResource Completed}"/>                    
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

call:

```
<Rectangle Name="computation1"  Style="{StaticResource iconStyle}"  Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

code behind:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }

    private bool _isCompleted;
    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return _isCompleted; }
        set { _isCompleted= value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsCompleted"); }
    }

private bool comp1(){
  ....
  IsCompleted = !IsCompleted;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Example Output:

groupbox1:
| -------------------------
| COMPUTATION 1:(TextBlock) 
| Icon for Completed or NotCompleted (Rectangle)
| Mean: (TextBlock)
| Some other stuff: 
| -------------------------
groupbox2:
| -------------------------
| COMPUTATION 2: (TextBlock)
| Icon for Completed or NotCompleted (Rectangle)
| Graph: (Image) 
| Some other stuff: 
| -------------------------

Comment: why do you need to set the same trigger in codebehind... the Triggers will be applied to any rectangle on which you set iconStyle

Comment: but different computations can have different end result, so some may be completed, others failed (not completed). so is it possible to set a different IsCompleted status for different icons? Or is this not possible?

Comment: yes.. every rectangle will look for the status of IsCompleted from its datacontext so they will act independently...

Comment: ok, but how do I set IsCompleted? In my code above it is just a  general call (global property) in my general class and not assigned to any rectangle or icon.

Comment: so if you have just one global property how can it control multiple computation status?

Comment: the global property above is just an example and the only way I know how to change a binding. Yes, it does not work for multiple computations. My question was how to adapt the code to work for multiple computations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to visualize the state of multiple computations you should have an ItemsControls that is bound to a collection of computation data items.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Computations}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource iconStyle}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The Computation item class could look like this:

```
public class Computation : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool isCompleted;
    public bool IsCompleted
    {
        get { return isCompleted; }
        set
        {
            isCompleted = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsCompleted"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and could be used in your MainWindow class like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Computations = new ObservableCollection<Computation>();
        Computations.Add(new Computation());
        Computations.Add(new Computation());
        Computations.Add(new Computation());

        DataContext = this;

        Computations[1].IsCompleted = true;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Computation> Computations { get; set; }
}
```

You may start reading about all this in the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) articles on MSDN.

Comment: wow, this is really an advanced version. 
The more Computations.Add(new Computation()); I do, the more Icons I generate. But I think this Icons are always placed in a stack underneath each other and I can't place single items at special positions? Is this right? Please see my edit for an output example.

Comment: Write a DataTemplate that suits your needs. That's also explained in the [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) article. An ItemsControl uses a (vertical) StackPanel by default. You may however change its ItemsPanel property, also shown in that article.